Obtener variable de php para realizar una consulta de SQL en ventana modal y mostrar imagen de tipo BLOB almacenada en MySQL
Estoy creando una página web para aprobar órdenes de compra. Este listado está almacenado en una base de datos de MYSQL y tiene una columna de tipo BLOB en donde se almacena el PNG de la orden de compra para que se visualice en una ventana modal. Esto ya lo tengo resuelto, pero necesito que según el botón del listado que seleccione se me muestre la imagen correspondiente, y para lograr esto estoy tratando de mandar el ID como variable para recibirla en PHP para realizar la consulta a la base de datos desde mi archivo de modal. He visto que se puede realizar con jQuery, AJAX o JavaScript pero no
entiendo muy bien esto aún.
Les dejo el código dividido según los archivos que tengo...
index.php
<?php
require_once("c://xampp/htdocs/pagina/vista/encabezado/encabezadoPag.php");
if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location:../../vista/principal/index.php");
}

require '../../conexion/bd.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM preRQs";

?>

<div class="container table-responsive">
    <table class="table align-midle">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><b>RQ</b></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><b>Proveedor</b></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><b>Importe</b></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><b>Moneda</b></th>
                <th style="text-align: center;"><b>Departamento</b></th>
                <th>&emsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            while ($listaRQs = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $BlobPNG  = $listaRQs['BlobPNG'];
                $id  = $listaRQs['id'];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $listaRQs['RQ'] ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $listaRQs['Proveedor'] ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $listaRQs['Importe'] ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $listaRQs['Moneda'] ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $listaRQs['Departamento'] ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                      <form action="mostrarOC.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><a href="#" id="mostrarOC" class="btn btn-outline-warning mostrarOC" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalOC" data-bs-id=<?= $listaRQs['id'] ?>><i class="fa-solid fa-file fa-xl"></i></a></form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php  }  ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php
    include 'modalOC.php';
    ?>   

    <script>
        let modalOC = document.getElementById('modalOC')
        modalOC.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', event => {
            let button = event.relatedTarget
            let id = button.getAttribute('data-bs-id')
            let inputId = modalOC.querySelector('.modal-body #id')
            let inputRQ = modalOC.querySelector('.modal-body #RQ')
            let url = "getOC.php"
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('id', id)
            fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData
                }).then(responsive => responsive.json())
                .then(data => {
                    inputId.value = data.id
                    inputRQ.value = data.RQ

                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
    </script>
</div>

<?php
require_once("c://xampp/htdocs/pagina/vista/encabezado/piePag.php");
?>

getOC.php
<?php 
require '../../conexion/bd.php';

$id = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$sql = "SELECT id, RQ FROM preRQs WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";
$resulSQL = $conexion->query($sql);
$resultado = $resulSQL->num_rows;

$listaRQ = [];

if($resultado > 0){
    $listaRQ = $resulSQL->fetch_array();
}

echo json_encode($listaRQ);
?>

modalOC.php
<?php
// ASÍ ES COMO HE INTENTADO OBTENER EL ID PARA LA CONSULTA

 $id = $_GET('id');
 //echo $id;
$sqlPNG = "SELECT * FROM preRQs WHERE id=$id";
$resultadoPNG = $conexion->query($sqlPNG);
while ($imgPNG = $resultadoPNG->fetch_assoc()) {
      $imagen=$imgPNG["BlobPNG"];
}

?>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalOC" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalOCLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="modalOCLabel"><?php echo $id; // echo $idRQ; ?></h1> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body mx-auto modal-lg">
        <form action="guarda.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
          <div class="mx-auto">
            <!-- <label for="RQ" class="form-label">idRQ:  </label> -->
            <input type="static" name="RQ" id="RQ" class="form-control" disabled>
            <img width='100%' src="data:image/png; base64,<?php echo  base64_encode($imagen); ?>">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

